# how to do a "Save as" window with tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

There is some way to create a save window as without having to do it from scratch in python (tkinter)?

```
from tkinter import *
```

How do you create a file save dialog using tkinter?

Comment: Not sure why this questions is marked as too broad... it is very clear. How do you create a file save dialog using tkinter? No ambiguity about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the asksaveasfilename dialog built in to tkinter

```
from tkinter import filedialog

directory = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

You can pass it additional options such as initialdirectory, file type filters, title etc. These are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html).

If you just want the dialog without a tkinter GUI then you need to withdraw the root window before calling the filedialog.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

directory = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: That opens an empty tkinter window alongside the save dialog. Is there any way I could not include that?

Comment: @Unknow0059 To remove the dialog, you need to withdraw the root dialog first. Do this with `root = tk.Tk(); root.withdraw()`. I've also edited my answer

Comment: Link of documentation "These are documented here." is not working. Please could you update the answer?

Comment: @martin-voj The effbot site is sadly gone (for the moment). I've updated the link to point to the official python docs. Slightly less clear but still describes the different dialog options.